# Given a list, output a new list whose length is 1 less than the original one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

Working with a question right now where it asks me to generate a new list from a given list who's length will be 1 less than that of the originals.

I think I know what concepts need to be used but I can't figure out how to put it together to work.

I have this so far but it adds up the numbers in the list instead of just listing them and taking 1 element away from the given list.

```
def forward_difference(elems):
    values = []
    total = 0

    for x in elems:
      total += x
      values = values[:-1]
      values.append(total)

    return values
  print (forward_difference([1,2,3,4]))
```

I know that in order to get shorten a list or take an element away, something like this can be done:

```
values = [1,2,3]
values = values[:-1]
print (values)
```

Output:

```
[1,2]
```

Still new to python and trying to grasp the concepts better, any help would be greatly appreciated!

The output that I expected was `[1,2,3]` but instead I keep getting `[1,3,6,10]`

Comment: You appear to already understand the answer to the question you asked, based on your second code sample. Can you clarify the original question, or explain what extra things you are trying to do not covered by your second code example? I don't understand the purpose of your first code sample.

Comment: What's wrong with `values = values[:-1]`?

Comment: @JeremyVisser  I just don't know how to put the code together I guess. What I want to know now how to do is getting my second part of the code that I mentioned somehow integrated in to the first part so that I get an output where any given list has 1 element taken away from it and the list doesn't add up the numbers that are inside it. If it helps I can post the original question straight from the review on to here.

Comment: @adrianp nothing is wrong with it, I just want to know how to get that working in the first part of the code.

Comment: Seems you already solve it, simply return elems[: -1] in your function

Comment: I want to make sure I understand: "I know how, given a list, to produce the desired output. I want to write a function that, when called with a list as a parameter, does that calculation and returns the result"... ?

Or is there some other rule that relates the input to the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop. The second code you posted does what you ask, the only thing left is to put it inside a function:

```
def forward_difference(elems):
    return elems[:-1]

print(forward_difference([1,2,3,4]))
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
```